# Quail-based Japanese conversion error

Tags: quail, japanese

The following error that I am reporting appears both in emacs-27.2 and emacs-28.2.

This question is written under the assumption that the reader is familiar with Quail and with Japanese syllabary.

When using `(set-language-environment "Japanese")` and `(set-input-method "japanese")` with Quail, when we type romaji, the displayed text is correctly converted to hiragana. If we want to convert the hiragana to katakana, we just follow the hiragana with "K", and the text display is correctly toggled to katakana. Typing "K" again will correctly toggle back to hiragana.

In most cases, this indeed works correctly. For example, typing "hoteru" correctly yields the hiragana "ほてる", and then following that with "K" switches it correctly to the katakana "ホテル". And then following that again with "K" correctly toggles it back to "ほてる".

However, when the word contains an embedded hyphen, the "K" toggling does not work properly.

For example, typing "ko-to" correctly yields the hiragana "こーと", and then typing "K" correctly converts it to the hiragana "コート". But then, if I type "K" again, the word does not get converted back to hiragana, and the katakana form remains.

This erroneous behavior occurs with all katakana words which contain an embedded hyphen. The existence of the hyphen in any word prevents that word from being toggled from katakana to hiragana when "K" is typed.

Can anyone suggest a way that this incorrect behavior can be fixed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That just sounds like a bug that you should report with `M-x report-emacs-bug`. However, you should check the latest version of Emacs (version 29) to make sure it’s not already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate that in Emacs 29.1.

Typing <kbd>K</kbd> calls this command:

```el
;; Convert Hiragana <-> Katakana in the current translation region.
(defun quail-japanese-toggle-kana ()
  (interactive)
  (setq quail-translating nil)
  (let ((start (overlay-start quail-conv-overlay))
        (end (overlay-end quail-conv-overlay)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (if (re-search-forward "\\cH" end t)
          (japanese-katakana-region start end)
        (japanese-hiragana-region start end)))
    (setq quail-conversion-str
          (buffer-substring (overlay-start quail-conv-overlay)
                            (overlay-end quail-conv-overlay)))))
```

The problem is that the hyphen is a valid character for *both* of those character sets, and consequently the test `(re-search-forward "\\cH" end t)`<sup>1</sup> succeeds in finding Hiragana text within the region of Katakana characters, which in turn makes the command use `japanese-katakana-region` instead of `japanese-hiragana-region` (which effectively does nothing, as the text was already Katakana characters).

It's not entirely clear to me whether the following change is safe/robust, but you might try testing whether *all* characters in the region are Hiragana characters:

```el
;; Convert Hiragana <-> Katakana in the current translation region.
(defun quail-japanese-toggle-kana ()
  (interactive)
  (setq quail-translating nil)
  (let ((start (overlay-start quail-conv-overlay))
        (end (overlay-end quail-conv-overlay)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (save-restriction
        (narrow-to-region start end)
        (if (re-search-forward "\\`\\cH*\\'" end t)
            (japanese-katakana-region start end)
          (japanese-hiragana-region start end))))
    (setq quail-conversion-str
          (buffer-substring (overlay-start quail-conv-overlay)
                            (overlay-end quail-conv-overlay)))))
```

I recommend you report this (including all of these details), using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug`.  I think you'll be in a better position than myself to establish whether my suggested change would be a sensible fix.  Potentially it's necessary to instead determine whether there are Hiragana characters which are *not* also Katakana characters, if it's intended for it to be valid for there to additionally be characters in the region which are neither of those categories.

---

<sup>1</sup> `"\\cH"` matches characters in category `H` which is "Japanese Hiragana characters of 2-byte character sets."

Moreover, the character `ー` belongs to all of the following categories:

```
(category-set-mnemonics (char-category-set ?ー))
=> ".HKLj|"
```

Which are:

```
(seq-map (lambda (c) (format "%c: %s" c (category-docstring c)))
         (category-set-mnemonics (char-category-set ?ー)))
```

- `.`: Base: Base characters (Unicode General Category L,N,P,S,Zs).
- `H`: 2-byte Hiragana.  Japanese Hiragana characters of 2-byte character sets.
- `K`: 2-byte Katakana.  Japanese Katakana characters of 2-byte character sets.
- `L`: Strong L2R.  Characters with "strong" left-to-right directionality, i.e. with L, LRE, or LRO Unicode bidi character type.
- `j`: Japanese.
- `|`: line breakable.  While filling, we can break a line at this character.

See also <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-categories`

Comment: Caveat: I have no understanding of Japanese text -- but because your question was explained so clearly, I *think* I've understood things sufficiently to provide an answer.

Comment: Your answer is indeed clear and EXCEPTIONALLY helpful!

I didn't have time yet to install and test with emacs-29.2, and so I very much appreciate that you did so. And I didn't know about `(report-emacs-bug)` until now, and I will definitely make use of it. I will try your proposed fix soon and then report back.

Comment: Also, I have an idea. In Hiragana, the hyphen is not normally used, and a different convention is utilized to indicate extended syllable sound. I will see if I can recode `quail-japanese-toggle-kana` (now that I know it's the appropriate function) in order to make use of that non-hyphen convention on the hiragana side, and then to hopefully be able to toggle between that and the hyphen via "K". I'll report those findings, also.

Comment: One more idea that I will try: I could re-write `quail-japanese-toggle-kana` (or create a new, alternate function) to split the buffer into individual characters and then do the hiragana<=>katakana toggling character-by-character. This should correctly convert "こーと" to "コート" and vice-versa. And of course I'll report my findings about this, as well.

Comment: Actually, your alternate version of `quail-japanese-toggle-kana` works, so I'm accepting it as an answer. I also have reported this issue via `report-emacs-bug`, so perhaps they will also come up with an alternative fix. But in any case, your fix works fine for me, and so I'm happy with it. Thank you!